# Reusable ngx-bootstrap modal as template or components

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a table with around 1000 rows in which ID column values are clickable. On click of ID value, I need to create a modal using `ngx-bootstrap`. This modal is reusable, and needs to be invoked from several pages of the application.
Now, I have 2 options.

1. create template based approach where the ID link/button is wrapped in one component with template. In DetailComponent html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">{{id}}</button>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
  .
  .
</ng-template>
```

Then use `<DetailsComponent [id]=“data.id”>`.  But in this case, I have to use the component for each row, so the component and the template will be initialized 1000 times. I believe it will have performance impact on the table load.

2. Other approach is, have the button on the parent component and create a separate component just for the modal display, and invoke modal display on click of ID. But in this case, I need a method to invoke `modalService.show` method in parent component. As the modal is reusable, I need this method in all pages where the modal is required, which will lead to code duplication.

Which one of this is better solution considering both performance and code duplication?

Comment: Can you explain option 1 in more details ?

Comment: Added code for option 1

Comment: You can use only one template with passing data of row, so you have only one template with data inside template will get from each row clicked, and this will not repeat template each time for each row too.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a module with component like `DetailModalModule` and `DetailModalComponent`. The module file should look something like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // Your other modules for this shared modal.
  ],
  declarations: [
    DetailModalComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DetailModalComponent,
  ],
})
export class DetailModalModule {
}
```

In the module of the component that you want to open this modal, you need to import this module and also the bootstrap modal module from `ngx-bootstrap`.

Then, you open the modal like this:

```js
openModal(item: MyItem): void {
  this.modalService.show(DetailModalComponent, {
    initialState: { data: item }
  });
}
```

There you have it, a shared modal module that you can open anywhere.

Comment: In this case, I need the openModal method for all pages I need the modal. I intend to avoid it, even if the method is 3 liner.

Comment: Then you can add a directive to the modal module that automatically does the opening without any TS code. You know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Create a modal component (DetailModalComponent.html)

```
<ng-template #template>
 <div class="modal-header">
 .
 .
</ng-template>
```

In DetailModalComponent.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.modalservice.show$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(product => {
  if (this.modalRef) {
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.template, this.config);
});
```

Then import and export in the shared or common module

Create a service for modal let's say **modalService.ts**

```
export class ModalService implements OnDestroy {
private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
private showSubject$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

show$: Observable<any> = this.showSubject$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));

constructor() { }

show(product: any): Observable<void> {
    this.showSubject$.next(product);
    return EMPTY
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

}

after that include detail component in app.component.html like this.

```
<detail-modal> </detail-modal>
```

Finally, you can call anywhere in the app using modalService

```
   this.modalservice.show(product).subscribe({
        complete: () => {
        // Your othe r logics
        }
    });
```